# ColorFunction with unexpected output

Tags: plotting, color

Here is a simple example of a rotational symmetric plot

```
ParametricPlot [{x, y }, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2 < 1], Mesh -> 5, 
MeshFunctions -> (Sqrt[#1^2 + #2^2 ] &), 
ColorFunction -> (Hue[  Sqrt[#1^2 + #2^2 ]  ] &), AxesLabel -> {x, y }]
```

[image]

I took the same function as meshfunction and colorfunction expecting rotational symmetrical mesh and coloring.

Any idea why the coloring isn't symmetric?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ColorFunctionScaling -> False
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, what an easy solution...

Comment: @UlrichNeumann:  Thanks... perhaps you'll want to accept $\checkmark$, to prevent distracting future solvers....

Comment: I tried it but have to wait for ten minutes...