# Plot3D: ColorFunction depending on (x,y) or z

Tags: plotting

While trying to answer [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/197292/plotting-f-x-i-y-mapsto-u-i-v-with-plot3d-and-mapping-v-to-color) I found out "weird" behavior of `ColorFunction`

```
Plot3D[x y, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue@(x y)]]
```

gives incorrect colors

[image]

the virtually identical code (from naive point of view)

```
Plot3D[x y, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue@z]]
```

gives correct plot

[image]

Also if you disable `ColorFunctionScaling` as many posts (e.g. [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/190198/colorfunction-with-unexpected-output)) suggest

```
Plot3D[x y, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue@(x y)], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

the colors are really messed up

[image]

**So the question - why are the first two plots different? A bug?**

I'm using Mathematica 11.1 on Linux.

Comment: The third plot only looks messed up because you're using too few `PlotPoints` (or too large a $xy$ range). You're correct in that `ColorFunctionScaling` is the issue for the first two plots, they are scaled differently, as is clear from the documentation.

Comment: @Roman Why are the first two plots scaled differently? They both have `ColorFunctionScaling ` true. Also `z=xy` so `Hue[z]` should be same as `Hue[xy]`

Comment: In the first plot, both $x$ and $y$ are scaled to the range $[0,1]$ and thus $x y$ (meaning the product of scaled-$x$ and scaled-$y$) is zero in the lower-left corner, left edge, and lower edge, and 1 in the upper-right corner. In the second plot, $z$ is scaled to the range $[0,1]$ and thus zero in the lower-right and upper-left corners, and 1 in the lower-left and upper-right corners. If you play with `Hue@x`, `Hue@y`, and `Hue@z` both with and without `ColorFunctionScaling` it all becomes clear.

Comment: From the documentation: "ColorFunctionScaling is an option for graphics functions that specifies whether arguments supplied to a color function should be scaled to lie between 0 and 1." Meaning that *every* argument of the color function will be scaled to $[0,1]$.

Comment: @Roman OK, I see it now.. somehow I wrongfully assumed that the `ColorFunctionScaling` controls the scaling of the value, not arguments. Honestly I'm not sure what's the point of scaling arguments to [0,1]. If you make it an answer I will gladly accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the documentation on `ColorFunctionScaling` says,

> **ColorFunctionScaling** is an option for graphics functions that specifies whether arguments supplied to a color function should be scaled to lie between 0 and 1.

In the first plot, $x$ and $y$ are both scaled to the range $[0,1]$. This means that the `ColorFunction` does not receive $x$ and $y$, but rather $(x+10)/20$ and $(y+10)/20$, and the color is then the hue of $(x+10)(y+10)/400$.

In the second plot, $z$ is scaled to the range $[0,1]$. This means that the `ColorFunction` does not receive $z$, but rather $(z+100)/200$ as the third argument.

In the third plot, the number of `PlotPoints` is too small and thus you see [Moiré effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern).

Comment: Increasing `PlotPoints` make it smoother, but you need to go with manually scaled `ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[0.01 x y]]` to make a desired effect.